# How to query multiple keys with Firebase GeoFire using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I've got a GeoFire query that is bringing back user id's or `keys`.  I'm getting back `keys` in sequence, but I'm getting several sequences.  How can I get the last updated sequence?

```
@IBAction func friendsNearMeACTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let geofireRef = self.ref.child("UserLocations")
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
        let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(self.location, withRadius: 20.6)
        circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            self.localUsers.append(key)
            self.getLocalUsers()
        })
    }

func getLocalUsers()
{
    print(self.localUsers)

}
```

This is what I'm getting back from `func getLocalUsers()`....

```
["WGueYzDjH4NW2vneHOyGmjf6PYB3"]
["WGueYzDjH4NW2vneHOyGmjf6PYB3", "Cg4pQj36ttNUuWNqtc16tIFmI0A2"]
["WGueYzDjH4NW2vneHOyGmjf6PYB3", "Cg4pQj36ttNUuWNqtc16tIFmI0A2", "N5pgqGEhW2f7PGGVmB3AQ8v1uPk2"]
```

How can I simply get the last array?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the GeoFire query is a continuous asynchronous call and needs the final code `observeReadyWithBlock` to feed the `self.localUsers()` the collected information only.  Here is the example...

```
let regionQuery = geoFire.queryWithRegion(self.region)
        regionQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered,  withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            var users = [String]()
            users.append(key)
            for keys in users
            {
                let user = keys
                allKeys.append(user)
            }
            self.localUsers = allKeys
            self.getLocalUsers()
        })

        regionQuery.observeReadyWithBlock({ () -> Void in
            self.getLocalUsers()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling getLocalUsers func every time the observer block is fired. You are calling it for every single result. You need to count the results and add 1 to the count every time the observer block is executed. When your count reaches the result count, call the getLocalUsers function once instead of 3 times. Try the code below. I have not tested it.

```
@IBAction func friendsNearMeACTN(sender: AnyObject){
    var i = 0//The counter
    let geofireRef = self.ref.child("UserLocations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
    let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(self.location, withRadius: 20.6)
    circleQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        self.localUsers.append(key)
        i += 1//Add one to i every time observer fires
        if i == self.key.count {//if counter (i) is equal to the keys returned call getLocalUsers func once
            self.getLocalUsers()
        }
    })
}

func getLocalUsers(){
    print(self.localUsers)
}
```